# Delete items from a list and put them in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops, foreach

I want to go throgh a list and delete an element randomly from it.

```
List<int> listArray = new List<int>();
int[] staticArray = new int[8];

listArray.Add(0);
listArray.Add(1);
listArray.Add(2);
listArray.Add(3);
listArray.Add(4);
listArray.Add(5);
listArray.Add(6);
listArray.Add(7);

while (listArray.Any()) {
    int chosen = ra.Next(0, 8);
    int loopIndex = 0;
    bool ok = false;

    if(listArray.Contains(chosen)) {
        ok = true;
    } else {
        ok = false;
        continue;
    }

    foreach (int item in cardIndexes.ToArray()) {
        if (item == chosen && ok == true) {
            staticArray[loopIndex].pathIndex = chosen;
            listArray.Remove(chosen);
            loopIndex++;
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!cardIndexes.Any()) break;
}
```

I don't understand, this code looks logic to me.
so we're going to loop throught a copy of the list (to be able to edit it) 
them choose a random number and check if i have it it that list.
then if it is, then delete it from the list and assgin it to the static array.
then increment the index of the array to go to another element.
I will be greatful if I get some help.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: The code above is not doing the right thing.

Comment: cardIndexes and staticArray missing declarations, can you post its.

Comment: Have you done: List<int> listArray = new List<int>(); ?

Comment: What is 'ra', where is the declaration for staticArray/cardIndexs?

Comment: Use collection initializers for more readable code: `List<int> listArray = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }`

Comment: By the way, it is not possible to remove items from a collection which is being looped over, isn't it? So removing from `listArray` while iterator is still used should not be possible.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek that only applies for when you use the iterator (like iterating with foreach)

Answer (score 0):

Each time you remove an item from your list your list size decreases with one.

So this won't work:

```
int chosen = ra.Next(0, 8);
```

Comment: Why would it not work, it simply returns a `"random"` value between 0 and 8.

Comment: if you mean that there might be not existing in the list 
    ***if(listArray.Contains(chosen)) {
        ok = true;
    } else {
        ok = false;
        continue;
    }***
This pice of code is taking care of it.

Comment: @Veleous: that will generate random number between 0 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good candidate for infinite loop. Check this:

```
var cardIndexes = new List<int>
{
    0,
    2,
    3,
    4
};

var nums = new List<int>
{
    0,
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,
    6,
    7,
    8
};

var random = new Random();
while (nums.Any())
{
    var randomVal = nums[random.Next(0, nums.Count)]; // pick random element from nums array.
    nums.Remove(randomVal); // always remove to avoid infinite loop.

    for (var i = 0; i < cardIndexes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (cardIndexes[i] == randomVal)
        {
            // do what you need to do, and break out.
            // staticArray[i].pathIndex = randomVal;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<int> listArray = new List<int>();

            listArray.Add(0);
            listArray.Add(1);
            listArray.Add(2);
            listArray.Add(3);
            listArray.Add(4);
            listArray.Add(5);
            listArray.Add(6);
            listArray.Add(7);

            Random ra = new Random();

            List<int> staticArray = new List<int>();

             //while there is an element in the list
             while (listArray.Any())
             {
             int chosen = ra.Next(0, 8);
             int loopIndex = 0;
             bool ok = false;

    if(listArray.Contains(chosen))
    {
        ok = true;
    }

    else 
    {
        ok = false;
        continue;
    }

     var cardIndexes = from value in listArray
                       where value == chosen
                       select value;


    foreach (int item in cardIndexes.ToArray())
    {
        if (item == chosen && ok == true) 
        {
            staticArray.Add(chosen);
          //  staticArray[loopIndex].pathIndex = chosen;
            listArray.Remove(chosen);
            loopIndex++;
            ok = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!cardIndexes.Any()) break;
                }
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> lst = (from l in Enumerable.Range(0, 100) select l).ToList();

List<int> remove = (from rv in Enumerable.Range(0, 10) where rv % 2 == 0 select rv).ToList();

lst.RemoveAll(v => remove.Contains(v));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<int> lst = (from l in Enumerable.Range(0, 100) select l).ToList();
        Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        List<int> Chosen = new List<int>();
        while (lst.Any(v => !Chosen.Contains(v)))
        {
            int current = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            if (!Chosen.Contains(current))
            {
                Chosen.Add(current);
            }
        }
```